# extract coefficients from glm in R

Tags: list, r

I have performed a logistic regression with the following result:

```
ssi.logit.single.age["coefficients"]
# $coefficients
#  (Intercept)          age 
# -3.425062382  0.009916508
```

I need to pick up the coefficient for `age`, and currently I use the following code:

```
ssi.logit.single.age["coefficients"][[1]][2]
```

It works, but I don't like the cryptic code here, can I use the name of the coefficient (i.e. `(Intercept)` or `age`)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is an extraction function called `coef` to get coefficients from models:

```
coef(ssi.logit.single.age)["age"]
```

Comment: then how about extracting the stand error? I need to calculate the 95% CI

Comment: see coef(summary(ssi.logit.single.age)) for a table including standard errors.  You can use confint.default(ssi.logit.single.age) to get confidence intervals based on +/- 1.96 SE. Or better, MASS::confint(ssi.logit.single.age) will give you profile confidence intervals, which are more accurate (although a tiny bit slower).

Answer (score 5):

I've found it, from [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-February/190021.html)

Look at the data structure produced by summary()

```
> names(summary(lm.D9))
  [1] "call"          "terms"         "residuals"     "coefficients"
  [5] "aliased"       "sigma"         "df"            "r.squared"
  [9] "adj.r.squared" "fstatistic"    "cov.unscaled"
```

Now look at the data structure for the coefficients in the summary:

```
> summary(lm.D9)$coefficients
             Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    5.032  0.2202177 22.850117 9.547128e-15
groupTrt      -0.371  0.3114349 -1.191260 2.490232e-01

> class(summary(lm.D9)$coefficients)
[1] "matrix"

> summary(lm.D9)$coefficients[,3]
(Intercept)    groupTrt
   22.850117   -1.191260
```

Comment: Also displaying the internal structure of an R object can be useful via `str()` function, e.g.: `str(summary(lm.D9))` in your example

Comment: Don't start delving around in objects like this! Use the extractor functions; in this case `coef()`. For example, look at the `$residuals` component. You can get model residuals by directly accessing `$residuals` but what are these? They certainly aren't what you might immediately think of as model residuals. Use `resid()` on the model and you can choose the type of residual.

Comment: ?? `> all.equal( residuals(lm.D9) , lm.D9$residuals)`   
[1] TRUE    (The glm residuals are the "working" residuals.)

Comment: @DWin @lokheart actually has a GLM and it was that to which I referred, even though the answer refers to a LM from the R-Help posting linked to. There (his GLM), `mod$residuals` is not the same as `resid(mod)`, and the former is unlikely to be something one would need routinely. The advice in the R-help posting and repeated in @lokheart's answer is not helpful nor recommended.

Comment: OK. Agreed, and not accurate either. Simpson's advice is especially important because the third column of the coefficients list is the p-value rather than any of the coefficients. The glm default for residuals() is not "working" which is what is stored in the model fit.