# Visualizing regression coefficient of a regression

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out the best way to display a list of 30+ coefficients on a regression of a continuous variable.

(This may belong more in [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), I am not sure.)

Here is my example:

```
library("nycflights13")
library(dplyr)

flights <- nycflights13::flights
flights<- sample_n (flights, 3000)

m1<- glm(formula = arr_delay ~ . , data = flights)

summary(m1)
```

Comment: Do you need `library(broom); tidy(m1)`

Comment: do summary(m1) and it should work

Answer (score 2):

An option is `dwplot` from `dotwhisker`

```
library(dotwhisker)
dwplot(m1)
```

As @BenBolker commented, by default, the `dwplot` scales regression coeffficients by 2 standard deviations of the predictor variable

---

Or if we need a data.frame/tibble, then use `tidy` from `broom`

```
library(broom)
tidy(m1)
```

Comment: may be worth noting that `dwplot()` by default scales the regression coefficients by 2SD of the predictor variable ... which is absolutely the right thing to do, but may be confusing if you're comparing the plot with the raw regression coefficients

Comment: Thanks. This looks excellent! Is there a way to filter only the significant coefficients with a different color? or to add the dotted line at 0 CI? (*Some of the examples show that but i'm looking for a how to guide). I am happy that I did not fo with heatmap :-)

Comment: @Stat.Enthus if you want to extract the coefffieints that are significant `sm1 <- summary(m1);sm1$coef[sm1$coeff[-1,4] < 0.05,]`

Comment: dotted line at 0 CI is `+ geom_vline(xintercept=0, lty=2)` (**much** better than extracting the significant coefficients).

Comment: I'm Trying to mark the non significant and the significant with different colors

Comment: @akrun this code is not returning any output, just running forever.. Does it work for you? library("nycflights13")
library(dplyr)

library(dotwhisker)

flights <- nycflights13::flights
flights<- sample_n (flights, 3000)

m1<- glm(formula = arr_delay ~ . , data = flights)

summary(m1)
dwplot(m1)

Comment: @BenBolker is this the right syntax?dwplot(m1 + geom_vline(xintercept=0, lty=2))

Answer (score 1):

This may help. You could select a specific coefficient with the following :

```
str(flights) # to print list of data features 
coef(m1)["age"] # here I just suppose that you have an axis called "age", you could select as many features coefficients as you want. For this you coud use a vector of relevant axis.
```

You could have a look at :

[extract coefficients from glm in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780152/extract-coefficients-from-glm-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** `dwplot` is still (a) right answer, but there's a lot to say about the details of how you're fitting this model (and why it takes a really really long time).

### glm vs lm

You're using `glm()` to fit a linear model, which isn't incorrect (and which would allow you to generalize to problems with count or binary responses). However, it's overkill in this case — `lm()` will work just fine, and be faster [considerably faster when it comes to generating confidence intervals etc.]

```r
system.time(m1 <- glm(formula = arr_delay ~ . , data = flights))  ## 6 seconds
system.time(m2 <- lm(formula = arr_delay ~ . , data = flights, x=TRUE)) ## 13 seconds
```

(the reason for including `x=TRUE` will be discussed below)

The time difference becomes more stark when tidying/computing confidence intervals:

```r
setTimeLimit(elapsed=600)
system.time(tidy(m1, conf.int=TRUE))   ## gave up after 10 minutes
system.time(tt <- tidy(m2, conf.int=TRUE))  ## 3.2 seconds
```

Tidying `glm`s by default uses `MASS::confint.glm()` to compute confidence intervals by likelihood profiling, which is more accurate than Wald (mean +/- 1.96*SE) intervals for non-Gaussian responses), but way slower.

### modeling choices

One of the reasons that everything is so slow is that there are *lots* of parameters (`length(coef(m2))` is 1761).  Why?

Although there are only 19 columns in the input data frame (so we might naively expect 18 coefficients), 4 of them are categorical, so get expanded to indicator variables:

```
catvars <- names(flights)[sapply(flights,is.character)]
sapply(catvars, function(x) length(unique(flights[[x]])))
## carrier tailnum  origin    dest 
##      15    1653       3      94
```

So, most of the coefficients come from modeling the departures of individual planes (`tailnum`) [`table(table(flights$tailnum))` shows that in this subsample of the data, more than half of the planes are recorded only once ...]  It might not make sense to include this variable (if I were going to use `tailnum`, I would treat it as a random effect, although that would add a lot of modeling complexity).

Let's proceed without `tailnum` (we will still have plenty of coefficients to worry about).

### plotting

At this point we're doing approximately what `dotwhisker::dwplot` does, but doing it by hand for more flexibility (in particular, ordering the terms by value).
The next step (1) extracts coefficients/conf int etc.; (2) scales non-binary variables by 2SD (using an internal function from `dotwhisker`); (3) drops the intercept; (4) makes `term` a factor ordered by the coefficient value and computes whether the term is significant (i.e., whether the lower and upper CI limits are both above or both below zero).

```
tt <- (tidy(m3, conf.int=TRUE)
    %>% dotwhisker::by_2sd(flights)
    %>% filter(term!="(Intercept)")
    %>% mutate(term=reorder(factor(term),estimate),
               sig=(conf.low*conf.high)>1)
)
```

Plot:

```
(ggplot(tt, aes(x=estimate,y=term,xmin=conf.low,xmax=conf.high))
    + geom_pointrange(aes(colour=sig))
    + geom_vline(xintercept=0,lty=2)
    + scale_colour_manual(values=c("black","red"))
)
```

[image]